# Should we update time periods in a Bibliometric analysis even after completing it, if it's found to be generating biased results due to recent study?

Tags: bibliometrics, literature-review

Suppose a bibliometric analysis was conducted to uncover new research discoveries, but it was later discovered that similar kinds of research had already been carried out. In such a scenario, what would be the appropriate course of action to pursue?

- Shall we update the time intervals?
- Should we update and rewrite both the findings and the article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a bibliometric study or literature review needs to be updated continuously during the peer review process. When I have published literature review articles, peer reviewers normally ask me to update the search to be as recent as possible. This is somewhat difficult to do, but it is a unique challenge for this kind of study. However painful to carry out, it is a reasonable expectation. A bibliometric study or literature review should be as current as possible at the time of publication.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I'll follow your words.